# mouseleave events on <option>

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to work around the issue that no events are fired on `mouseleave`/`enter` on `<option>` for `<select>` (Firefox, IE, Google Chrome, etc)

First issue (fixed): dropdown `hide()`s as soon as `mouseleave`s `<option>` with this code:

```
$("#dropdown_year").mouseleave(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
```

Second issue: click the dropdown, move mouse down beyond the dropdown, click the page anywhere. The dropdown stays down...

Is there an (elegant) solution to this?

http://jsfiddle.net/f6fvg/

=====================

HTML

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" id="hover_content_swap">EVENT
        <span id="hover_content_swap_off">2012</span>
        <span id="hover_content_swap_on">
            <form style="display:inline" class="dynamic_select">
                <select id="dropdown_year">
                    <option value="event2012.php" selected="selected">2012</option>
                    <option value="event2011.php">2011</option>
                    <option value="event2010.php">2010</option>
                </select>
                </form>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$('#hover_content_swap_on').hide();   //HIDE NOW, SHOW ON HOVER

// SWAP CONTENT VISIBILITY ON HOVER
$('#hover_content_swap').hover(function () {
    $('#hover_content_swap_off').hide();
    $('#hover_content_swap_on').show();
}, function() {
    $('#hover_content_swap_off').show();
    $('#hover_content_swap_on').hide();
});

// PREVENT UNINTENDED EVENT PROPAGATION WHEN HOVERING 'OPTIONS'
$("#dropdown_year").mouseleave(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f6fvg/

Answer (score 0):

This is a really cool idea (to switch in an editable field on a `hover` event).

Take a look at this [version of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6fvg/4/).  I've added a wrapper `div` and attached a `click` event to it.  The click event performs the "hover-out" action to reset the objects.

You don't have to use a wrapper `div` - you could attach the `click` event to an existing container in DOM.  Based on your question, it sounds like you would be looking for an event on the `body`, but I'm not sure how jsfiddle handles that.

EDIT:  Here is an [updated version of the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6fvg/5/).  This version includes a `click` event for the `select` to stop that event from bubbling, which is mentioned in a comment below.

Comment: I had that on the table at some point, but the #wrapper.click() event fires when the dropdown is clicked, so unless you click-and-hold-and-choose-an-option the dropdown will hide instantly. 2 `<div>`s on either side of the hover element would do it, but that's just to quirky.

Comment: @sumsaricum - I've modified the jsfiddle to account for the `click` event of the `select`. Have a look (link is in the answer above).

Comment: Take note that this mouse-based interaction doesn't work at all on mobile/touch platforms where there is no mouse.  Otherwise, it's still a cool idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

jQuery:

```
$("#dropdown_year").change(function(){
    $("#hover_content_swap_off").text( $("#dropdown_year option:selected").text() ); 
});
```

HTML contenteditable [<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable) [<sup>WHATWG</sup>](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#editing-0):

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" id="hover_content_swap">EVENT
        <span id="hover_content_swap_off" contenteditable="true">2012</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Comment: The jQuery option works just as if no propagation preventing code was used, ie. unless you click-and-hold-and-choose-an-option the dropdown will hide instantly when the hover element border is crossed.

The HTML option has no effect. To be honest I have no idea what it was supposed to do?! :/

Comment: 1. click, select and click - this is the way with select. If you want only hover, then you should use lists. 2. You will get it you read at least one of the links.

Comment: "1. click, select and click" is not the result of the jQuery option. "click & hold, move to option, release" is the result.
2. I read all three, but I still don't understand why making the span editable would have any effect (in fact it doesn't). Would you care to explain the theory?